# Ist "Save the date" in der deutschen Sprache geläufig?

Tags: usage, idiom, expression, synonym

Kann der englische Ausdruck "Save the date" als prägnanter Ersatz für "Reservieren Sie dieses Datum" in der deutsche Sprache benutzt werden?

Zum Beispiel in einer Ankündigung für eine Veranstaltung wie:

> Am 29.10.2017 stellen wir Ihnen die Neuheiten in unserem Superprodukt XYZ vor. 
> Save the date.

Comment: Ich sehe als deutschen Ausdruck an sich öfter "Bitte Termin vormerken!"

Comment: ... oder "bitte den Termin freihalten".

Comment: Warum schon wieder etwas englisches für Dinge, die man gut auf Deutsch sagen kann? Stick to German.

Comment: @äüö "but it's soooo kewl!" ... Ich hab zwei (deutschsprachige) Kollegen, die ihrer Konversation untereinander mit ca. 5-10% englischen Worten "würzen". Sachen wie "Shortly hab ich mein flat gechanged, weil ich die andere area mehr like". Grausig

Comment: @Tommylee2k: :-) Das erinnert mich irgendwie daran, wie es ganz früher schick war, Französisch zu sprechen, um vornehmer zu wirken...

Comment: @tofro: "Vormerken" heißt aber nur, dass man den Termin schon in den Kalender einträgt und dass Details noch folgen. Dass der Termin auch *freigehalten* werden muss, kommt dabei nicht so stark wie bei "save the date" (oder natürlich bei guidots "freihalten") zum Ausdruck.

Comment: @Tommylee2k nach der Pubertät sollte das vorbei sein.

Comment: @Gerhardh nur gehen manche leider von der Pubertät direkt in die Midlife-Crisis über...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper irgendwie ist es für mich selbstverständlich, dass ich einen vorgemerkten Termin auch freihalte

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Bei "Save the Date" geht's auch nicht um das Freihalten, sondern nur darum, dass man sich merkt, dass an dem Termin was wichtiges ist. Ob man teilnimmt oder nicht, muss zu diesem Zeitpunkt noch nicht feststehen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde sagen, das kommt auf die Zielgruppe an. Für Hochzeiten bekommt man heute häufig "Save the date"-Karten.

Wenn Du eine ältere Zielgruppe ansprichst, solltest Du vielleicht sowas schreiben wie: "Tragen Sie sich das Datum schon einmal ein" oder "Merken Sie sich schon einmal den 29.10.2017. An diesem Tag stellen wir ..."